# display featured image in post - wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I have installed wordpress on my local wampp server. The question refers to the default theme that comes with wordpress after the first install(twentytwelve).

I have created a test post and I am trying to display the featured image inside the post. As I understand I need to use the function:

```
   the_post_thumbnail
```

However, as I am not very familiar with wordpress theme development I do not know how to use this function or what file from the template files I should modify. Thanks a lot for any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to call that function from *within* the [WordPress Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).  Using the twentytwelve theme as your example, open `single.php` (which is the default template for the detail view of your single post).  You can use this function anywhere between lines 15 - 27.

If you want to display the image in a **Page** (not a Post) then you'll edit `page.php` instead.

The Codex has more detailed information on how to use the [`the_post_thumnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) function (for example, how to request a different image size).

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple:
Open your style.css
Search

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

or search

.list-view .site-content .cat-links,
    .list-view .site-content .type-post .entry-content,
    .list-view .site-content .type-page .entry-content,
    .list-view .site-content .type-post .entry-summary,
    .list-view .site-content .type-page .entry-summary,
    .list-view .site-content footer.entry-meta {
        /*display: none; jay*/
    }

and comment this line
display: none;
```

Thats all, problem will be solved.